# Ubuntu 12.10: Package libc6-dev-i386 is not available

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, apt, package-management

I'm building 32 bit boost thread libraries on 32 bit Ubuntu 12.10. When building I get the error
`/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:27: error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory`

I googled the problem and from reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412548/gnu-stubs-32-h-no-such-file-or-directory) it seems I need to install libc6-dev-i386. However, when I run `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386` I get:

```
Package libc6-dev-i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libc6-dev-i386' has no installation candidate
```

Can anyone help me to locate this package?

Edit, more info:

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but `uname -m -p -i` gives `i686 i686 i686`.

`ls /usr/include/gnu/` gives `libc-version.h  lib-names.h  option-groups.h  stubs-64.h  stubs.h`.

`ls /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu` gives `libc-version.h  lib-names.h  option-groups.h  stubs-32.h  stubs.h`.

I added `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu` to `$PATH` but it didn't help, I still get the same error when trying to build the 32 bit boost thread libraries.

More info:

I've now tried this with Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm getting exactly the same behaviour. With this install `uname -i` gives `i386`.

Comment: Here I can install it without any problems. Did you try `sudo apt-get update` before?

Comment: @guntbert, yes, I've done an apt-get update already.

Comment: try with `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386`

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the proper solution but it will download the package for you.

Type "software sources" in the `dash`, and change your server to `"Main server"`. This is because some (one of which may be yours) do not maintain the package on their servers. Refer to the image below showing the source changed to "Main server". Then do a `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386`. Repeating, this is not the proper solution, but will probably download the package for you.

[image: software sources]

Comment: Thanks, Jobin. I tried this but unfortunately I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: Are you sure you did a `sudo apt-get update` after changing the source?

Comment: Yes, I did the update.

Comment: I think, as I'm on a 32 bit OS, that I shouldn't need libc6-dev-i386. I guess the question is then why can the compiler not find `stubs-32.h`. I've found that if I copy `stubs-32.h` from `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu` to '/usr/include/gnu` then I can compile the boost thread libraries without a problem. I'd still like to understand why I need to copy that file though?

Comment: @eoinmullan: Do you mean to say that `libc6-dev-i386` is for the `64-bit` version? I am not sure but `i386` probably means `32 bit`. And about the copy that you need to do is may be because `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu` may not be there in the folders that `gcc` searches to find the header files by default, so if you can manually add that folder, you need not copy it anywhere, I guess.

Comment: I figure `libc6-dev-i386` is to allow you to compile _for_ 32 bit _on_ a 64 bit machine. That's why I figure I shouldn't need it. Yeah, I guess I could equally have had `gcc` search in `usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu`, I expect that would have worked too. But I'd like to understand why `stubs-32.h` was not in `/usr/include/gnu` but `stubs-64.h` was.