# 16.04 LTS package libc6-dev-i386 is not installed

Tags: 16.04, package-management

Whenever I try to install something, it fails to install and gives me this message:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-5-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.23-0ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried following multiple guides on how to fix this, ([Example1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246241/ubuntu-12-10-package-libc6-dev-i386-is-not-available?rq=1), [Example2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246241/ubuntu-12-10-package-libc6-dev-i386-is-not-available),[Example3](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1676946)) but none have so far solved the problem.
If you have a solution or a link to a solution, it would be quite helpful.
I can also post any other results if it will help you.

```
andreas@Bob:~$ sudo apt install -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-twitter checkbox-ng cli-common friends friends-dispatcher
  friends-facebook friends-twitter gcc-4.8-base:i386 gcc-4.9-base:i386
  gir1.2-ebook-1.2 gir1.2-ebookcontacts-1.2 gir1.2-edataserver-1.2
  gir1.2-messagingmenu-1.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gnome-icon-theme-symbolic
  gstreamer0.10-nice gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio
  gstreamer0.10-x gstreamer1.0-clutter gtk3-engines-unico icedtea-netx
  icedtea-netx-common iproute javascript-common libamd2.3.1 libass4
  libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libbasicusageenvironment0
  libbind9-90 libboost-date-time1.54.0 libcamd2.3.1 libcamel-1.2-45
  libccolamd2.8.0 libcdr-0.0-0 libcgmanager0:i386 libcholmod2.1.2
  libcmis-0.4-4 libcolamd2.8.0 libcolord1 libcolord1:i386
  libcrypt-passwdmd5-perl libcuda1-352 libdirac-encoder0 libdns100 libdvbpsi8
  libegl1-mesa-drivers libegl1-mesa-lts-vivid libelfg0 libexiv2-12
  libfarstream-0.1-0 libfriends0 libgbm1-lts-vivid libgconf2-4 libgdata13
  libgee2 libgegl-0.2-0 libgif4 libgif4:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid
  libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid
  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386 libglade2-0 libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid
  libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid:i386 libgles1-mesa-lts-vivid libgles2-mesa-lts-vivid
  libglew1.10 libglewmx1.10 libgnome-bluetooth11 libgnome-control-center1
  libgnome-desktop-3-7 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgroupsock1
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libgtop2-7
  libhdb9-heimdal libilmbase6 libimobiledevice4 libisc95 libisccc90
  libisccfg90 libisl10 libjasper1:i386 libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0
  libjs-xmlextras libkdc2-heimdal liblivemedia23 libllvm3.6 libllvm3.6:i386
  liblwres90 libmagick++5 libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5
  libmbim-glib0 libminiupnpc8 libmono-2.0-1 libmono-2.0-dev libmono-profiler
  libmonoboehm-2.0-1 libmonoboehm-2.0-dev libmonosgen-2.0-1 libmspub-0.0-0
  libmysqlclient18:i386 libnih-dbus1:i386 libnih1:i386 libnl-route-3-200
  libntdb1 libopenexr6 libopenobex2 liborcus-0.6-0 libpangox-1.0-0:i386
  libparted0debian1 libplist1 libpocketsphinx1 libpoppler44 libpostproc52
  libprotobuf8 libqmi-glib0 libqpdf13 libqt5qml-graphicaleffects
  libqt5sensors5 libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin libraw9 librhythmbox-core8
  libsphinxbase1 libsvga1 libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-journal0
  libsystemd-login0 libt1-5 libtar0 libthumbnailer0 libts-0.0-0
  libumfpack5.6.2 libunityvoice1 libupower-glib1 libusageenvironment1
  libusbmuxd2 libvpx1:i386 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common
  libwnck-common libwpd-0.9-9 libwpg-0.2-2 libwps-0.2-2 libwxbase2.8-0
  libwxgtk-media2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 libxatracker2-lts-vivid libxcb-util0
  libxft2:i386 libxtables10 linux-headers-3.19.0-25
  linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-31
  linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-34
  linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid
  linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic
  linux-image-generic-lts-vivid mono-jay nvidia-opencl-icd-352
  obex-data-server perlmagick python-commandnotfound python-dbus-dev
  python-gconf python-gdbm python-gnomekeyring python-gobject python-ibus
  python-libxml2 python-notify python-ntdb python-pexpect python-ptyprocess
  python-renderpm python-reportlab python-reportlab-accel python-requests
  python-wxgtk2.8 python3-checkbox-ng qml-module-qtquick-dialogs
  qml-module-qtquick-localstorage qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets
  qml-module-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-privatewidgets-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin-assets
  qtdeclarative5-window-plugin rhythmbox-mozilla sphinx-voxforge-hmm-en
  sphinx-voxforge-lm-en telepathy-indicator tsconf ttf-dejavu-extra
  ubuntu-extras-keyring unity-lens-friends unity-scope-audacious
  unity-scope-clementine unity-scope-gmusicbrowser unity-scope-gourmet
  unity-scope-guayadeque unity-scope-musique unity-voice-service
  visualboyadvance xfonts-mathml xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-vivid
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 343 not upgraded.
39 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,262 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,936 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 677750 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev-i386 (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/fpu_control.h', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64:i386 2.23-0ubuntu5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The same after sudo apt clean and sudo apt autoclean:

```
    andreas@Bob:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for andreas: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-twitter checkbox-ng cli-common friends friends-dispatcher
  friends-facebook friends-twitter gcc-4.8-base:i386 gcc-4.9-base:i386
  gir1.2-ebook-1.2 gir1.2-ebookcontacts-1.2 gir1.2-edataserver-1.2
  gir1.2-messagingmenu-1.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gnome-icon-theme-symbolic
  gstreamer0.10-nice gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio
  gstreamer0.10-x gstreamer1.0-clutter gtk3-engines-unico icedtea-netx
  icedtea-netx-common iproute javascript-common libamd2.3.1 libass4
  libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libbasicusageenvironment0
  libbind9-90 libboost-date-time1.54.0 libcamd2.3.1 libcamel-1.2-45
  libccolamd2.8.0 libcdr-0.0-0 libcgmanager0:i386 libcholmod2.1.2
  libcmis-0.4-4 libcolamd2.8.0 libcolord1 libcolord1:i386
  libcrypt-passwdmd5-perl libcuda1-352 libdirac-encoder0 libdns100 libdvbpsi8
  libegl1-mesa-drivers libegl1-mesa-lts-vivid libelfg0 libexiv2-12
  libfarstream-0.1-0 libfriends0 libgbm1-lts-vivid libgconf2-4 libgdata13
  libgee2 libgegl-0.2-0 libgif4 libgif4:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid
  libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid
  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386 libglade2-0 libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid
  libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid:i386 libgles1-mesa-lts-vivid libgles2-mesa-lts-vivid
  libglew1.10 libglewmx1.10 libgnome-bluetooth11 libgnome-control-center1
  libgnome-desktop-3-7 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgroupsock1
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libgtop2-7
  libhdb9-heimdal libilmbase6 libimobiledevice4 libisc95 libisccc90
  libisccfg90 libisl10 libjasper1:i386 libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0
  libjs-xmlextras libkdc2-heimdal liblivemedia23 libllvm3.6 libllvm3.6:i386
  liblwres90 libmagick++5 libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5
  libmbim-glib0 libminiupnpc8 libmono-2.0-1 libmono-2.0-dev libmono-profiler
  libmonoboehm-2.0-1 libmonoboehm-2.0-dev libmonosgen-2.0-1 libmspub-0.0-0
  libmysqlclient18:i386 libnih-dbus1:i386 libnih1:i386 libnl-route-3-200
  libntdb1 libopenexr6 libopenobex2 liborcus-0.6-0 libpangox-1.0-0:i386
  libparted0debian1 libplist1 libpocketsphinx1 libpoppler44 libpostproc52
  libprotobuf8 libqmi-glib0 libqpdf13 libqt5qml-graphicaleffects
  libqt5sensors5 libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin libraw9 librhythmbox-core8
  libsphinxbase1 libsvga1 libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-journal0
  libsystemd-login0 libt1-5 libtar0 libthumbnailer0 libts-0.0-0
  libumfpack5.6.2 libunityvoice1 libupower-glib1 libusageenvironment1
  libusbmuxd2 libvpx1:i386 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common
  libwnck-common libwpd-0.9-9 libwpg-0.2-2 libwps-0.2-2 libwxbase2.8-0
  libwxgtk-media2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 libxatracker2-lts-vivid libxcb-util0
  libxft2:i386 libxtables10 linux-headers-3.19.0-25
  linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-31
  linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-34
  linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid
  linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic
  linux-image-generic-lts-vivid mono-jay nvidia-opencl-icd-352
  obex-data-server perlmagick python-commandnotfound python-dbus-dev
  python-gconf python-gdbm python-gnomekeyring python-gobject python-ibus
  python-libxml2 python-notify python-ntdb python-pexpect python-ptyprocess
  python-renderpm python-reportlab python-reportlab-accel python-requests
  python-wxgtk2.8 python3-checkbox-ng qml-module-qtquick-dialogs
  qml-module-qtquick-localstorage qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets
  qml-module-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-privatewidgets-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin-assets
  qtdeclarative5-window-plugin rhythmbox-mozilla sphinx-voxforge-hmm-en
  sphinx-voxforge-lm-en telepathy-indicator tsconf ttf-dejavu-extra
  ubuntu-extras-keyring unity-lens-friends unity-scope-audacious
  unity-scope-clementine unity-scope-gmusicbrowser unity-scope-gourmet
  unity-scope-guayadeque unity-scope-musique unity-voice-service
  visualboyadvance xfonts-mathml xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-vivid
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 343 not upgraded.
39 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,262 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,936 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc6-dev-i386 amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5 [1,262 kB]
Fetched 1,262 kB in 0s (3,790 kB/s)      
(Reading database ... 677750 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev-i386 (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/fpu_control.h', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64:i386 2.23-0ubuntu5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu5_amd64.d‌​eb && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade:

```
    Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Hit:4 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Get:5 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Ign:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Sources [60.1 kB] 
Get:8 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [213 kB]
Get:10 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Sources [231 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages [206 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [68.1 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [43.1 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [32.1 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [37.0 kB]
Get:16 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [472 kB]
Hit:17 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                    
Get:19 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [463 kB]
Get:20 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [306 kB]
Get:21 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [194 kB]
Get:22 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [397 kB]
Get:23 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [392 kB]
Get:24 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [133 kB]
Get:25 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [162 kB]
Get:26 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,520 B]
Get:27 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,328 B]
Fetched 3,722 kB in 1s (3,644 kB/s) 
AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
343 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-5-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not installed
 libc6-dev-x32
```

: Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.23-0ubuntu5) but it is not installed

Comment: Please try `sudo apt install f`

Comment: I did and posted the results

Comment: Please run `sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoclean` and try again...

Comment: There you go George

Comment: Lost the minus -- that should have been sudo apt install -f

Comment: Please run: `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`...

Comment: There it is George